# Dashboard design: few CRUD functionalities in /admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make admin panel in my app /admin that will be used to CRUD few thinks, for example Users, Companies and Wastes.

I want to do this all from one page, from /admin page.

Sketched example: http://cl.ly/3v2L3Q260g2B2M2H0J0G

Where is some simple way for making this? I can list, it's not a problem, but when I want to add new, or edit, I get stucked with routes and I don't know what more :D

I have controllers and models for Users, Companies and Wastes, but I don't know how to properly organize them.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are actually looking for an RBAC system (role based access control). A very good way to do that is by using devise and CanCan.

For more info :

http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/

Comment: I already have seted RBAC system with devise and cancan, but I need to make dashboard where I can from one page do add new users, new companies, and list them for example.